# Python pandas: dynamically change values in unspecified number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple data frame which might look like this:

```
| Label   | Average BR_1 | Average BR_2 | Average BR_3 | Average BR_4 |
| ------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ | ------------ |
| Label 1 | 50           | 30           | 50           | 50           |
| Label 2 | 60           | 20           | 50           | 50           |
| Label 3 | 65           | 50           | 50           | 50           |
```

What I would like to be able to do is to add a `%` symbol in every column.

I know that I can do something like this for every column:

`df['Average BR_1'] = df['Average BR_1'].astype(str) + '%'`

However, the problem is, that I read in the data from a CSV file which might contain more of these columns, so instead of `Average BR_1` to `Average BR_4`, it might contain `Average BR_1` to say `Average BR_10`.

So I would like this change to happen automatically for every column which contains `Average BR_` in its column name.

I have been reading about `.loc` but I managed only to change column values to an entirely new value like so:

`df.loc[:, ['Average BR_1', 'Average BR_2']] = "Hello"`

Also, I haven't yet been able to implement regex here.

I tried with a list:

```py
colsArr = [c for c in df.columns if 'Average BR_' in c]
print(colsArr)
```

But I did not manage to implement this with `.loc`.

I suppose I could do this using a loop, but I feel like there must be some better pandas solution, but I can not figure it out.

Could you help and point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# extract the column names that need to be updated
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Average BR')]

# update the columns
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).add('%')

print(df)
     Label Average BR_1 Average BR_2 Average BR_3 Average BR_4
0  Label 1          50%          30%          50%          50%
1  Label 2          60%          20%          50%          50%
2  Label 3          65%          50%          50%          50%
```

[working example](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/9d4469b1.py)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) and [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
df.update(df.filter(like='Average BR_').astype('str').add('%'))
df
```

Out:

```
   Label     Average BR_1   Average BR_2   Average BR_3   Average BR_4
0  Label 1            50%            30%            50%            50%
1  Label 2            60%            20%            50%            50%
2  Label 3            65%            50%            50%            50%
```